# TypeScript: Restrict keyof type

Tags: typescript

```
interface StorageType {
    [key: string]: StorageType | string | number
}

interface StorageSchema extends StorageType {
    username: string,
    user: {
        name: string,
        age: number,
        address?: {
            street: string,
            aptNumber: number,
        },
    },
    email: string,
    totalItems: number,
};

type InputType =  keyof StorageSchema;
```

How do I restrict InputType to only for key of StorageSchema and not any string.

Comment: Why have the extends ? Do you want to ensure the properties in `StorageSchema ` are constrained somehow ?  Do you want to be able to put anyting in `StorageScehma` and just want the known keys

Comment: To get the known keys of a type with an index signature you can use this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=3&pln=19&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPZTgcwgFQE8AHFAbwChlrkBtAawkIC5kBnMKUHAXVfSy4CJFAB92nbsnEgArgFsARtAoBfChVCRYiFAOx5UCABYR5cZBAAekEABM2aTAeGlklGslltoIOPIhWDi4QHAAaKhpvaFYPTxo-AKDJUIj4miFWOSVoNPTkODs7KAg2NgB+WMj8mmCICDBkkPDqmoLiMAA5BWUoLJ7c1s9VPOoR1rM4YAAbJu5R5EwwOGmASUh5Nn6cqAjVAG4NMBFkVZBiWTAiNwBeakZCDBh3VtoABWRQZAenp0FDEyTAqOYJSay2BzIN7lZAgCAANxiUJ4yFYcBAhDU+yAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the known keys of a type using a mapped type:

```
type InputType =  keyof {
    [P in keyof StorageSchema as string extends P? never: P] : unknown
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPZTgcwgFQE8AHFAbwChlrkBtAawkIC5kBnMKUHAXVfSy4CJFAB92nbsnEgArgFsARtAoBfChVCRYiFAOx5UCABYR5cZBAAekEABM2aTAeGlklGslltoIOPIhWDi4QHAAaKhpvaFYPTxo-AKDJUIj4miFWOSVoNPTkODs7KAg2NgB+WMj8mmCICDBkkPDqmoLiMAA5BWUoLJ7c1s9VPOoR1rM4YAAbJu5R5EwwOGmASUh5Nn6cqAjVAG4NMBFkVZBiWTAiNwBeakZCDBh3VtoABWRQZAenp0FDEyTAqOYJSay2BzIN7lZAgCAANxiUJ4yFYcBAhDU+yAA)

The `as` clause will go though all the fields and indexes on a type and pass them through the conditional type. `string extends P` will only be true for `string`, so that will be mapped to `never` meaning it will be removed from the resulting type. The other keys will remain unaffected and we can use `keyof` to get them from the mapped type.